# New to python. Menu option to "Go Back"

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop, menu

I'm racking my brain on this and I'm sure it's unnecessary. I've tried looking for the answer online but it's leading me nowhere.

I'm writing a simple menu script (probably not the nicest format). In prompt 2, 3, 4 I'm in need of an option to get back to the previous prompt. Based on what I've found I just keep looping myself into a bigger and bigger issue.

Here is what I have:

```
print("\nPlease select an action:")
print("\n1. Run")
print("2. Swim")

user_input1 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

if user_input1 == "1":
    user_selected_action = "run"
elif user_input1 == "2":
    user_selected_action = "swim"
else:
    print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    exit()

print("\nPlease select an environment:")
print("\n1. Outdoors")
print("2. In a Gym")

user_input2 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

if user_input2 == "1":
    user_selected_cluster = 'Outdoors'
elif user_input2 == "2":
    user_selected_cluster = 'Gym'
else:
    print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    exit()


print("\nPlease select an day:")
print("\n1. Saturday")
print("2. Sunday")

user_input3 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

if user_input3 == "1":
    user_selected_action = "Sat"
elif user_input3 == "2":
    user_selected_action = "Sun"
else:
    print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    exit()

print("\nPlease select a time of day:")
print("\n1. Day")
print("2. Night")

user_input4 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

if user_input4 == "1":
    user_selected_cluster = 'AM'
elif user_input4 == "2":
    user_selected_cluster = 'PM'
else:
    print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    exit()
```

I've tried a variety of while loops and even turning these into functions, which to be honest, I don't have a complete grasp of.

Every solution has just ended up with me looping the prompt I'm on, looping the entire script, or ending the script after prompt_1

Honestly would prefer to learn it instead of someone doing it but I can't even find good videos that address the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Python (like many other languages) does not have a `go to` option.

> The "goto" statement, which allows for unconditional jumps in program flow, was considered to be a bad programming practice because it can lead to confusing and difficult-to-maintain code. Instead, Python uses structured control flow statements, such as if, for, and while loops, which encourage clear and organized code that is easy to understand and debug.

However, you can put the code into functions to achieve the same result, like this:

```py
def main():
    ''' the main module '''

    # have 3 attempts at each question, then move on.
    for i in range(3):
        x = action_01()
        if x != 'invalid': break

    for i in range(3):
        x = action_02()
        if x != 'invalid': break

    for i in range(3):
        x = action_03()
        if x != 'invalid': break

    for i in range(3):
        x = action_04()
        if x != 'invalid': break




def action_01():

    print("\nPlease select an action:")
    print("\n1. Run")
    print("2. Swim")

    user_input1 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

    if user_input1 == "1":
        user_selected_action = "run"
    elif user_input1 == "2":
        user_selected_action = "swim"
    else:
        user_selected_action = "invalid"
        print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    return user_selected_action

def action_02():
    print("\nPlease select an environment:")
    print("\n1. Outdoors")
    print("2. In a Gym")

    user_input2 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

    if user_input2 == "1":
        user_selected_action = 'Outdoors'
    elif user_input2 == "2":
        user_selected_action = 'Gym'
    else:
        user_selected_action = "invalid"
        print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    return user_selected_action

def action_03():
    print("\nPlease select an day:")
    print("\n1. Saturday")
    print("2. Sunday")

    user_input3 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

    if user_input3 == "1":
        user_selected_action = "Sat"
    elif user_input3 == "2":
        user_selected_action = "Sun"
    else:
        user_selected_action = "invalid"
        print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    return user_selected_action

def action_04():
    print("\nPlease select a time of day:")
    print("\n1. Day")
    print("2. Night")

    user_input4 = input("\nPlease make your selection: ")

    if user_input4 == "1":
        user_selected_action = 'AM'
    elif user_input4 == "2":
        user_selected_action = 'PM'
    else:
        user_selected_action = "invalid"
        print("Invalid option selected. Run script again.")
    return user_selected_action
    




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note, there are even more efficient ways, but this will be a good starting point for you.